# Find a splitting field for $f(x) = x^6 − 2 $ over $GF(7)$ .

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field, galois-extensions

I encountered a question which asks the following;

Find a splitting field for $f(x) = x^6 − 2 $ over $GF(7)$. Is $f(x)$ irreducible over $GF(7)$? If
not, factorise $f(x)$ into irreducibles over $GF(7)$.

Here is what I did, and I just wanted to see if I'm doing it right ? Any help is much appreciated :).

$f(x)=x^6-2$ over $GF(7)$.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x) \Rightarrow \alpha^6=2 \Rightarrow\alpha^7=2\alpha$

$2\alpha\neq\alpha$ as $\alpha \neq 0$ and $2\neq1$ in $GF(7) \Rightarrow \alpha \notin GF(7)$.

So next we try

$\alpha^{7^{2}}=(\alpha^7)^7=(2\alpha)^7=128\alpha^7=5\alpha^7=10\alpha=3\alpha$

But $3\alpha \neq \alpha$ as $\alpha \neq0$ and $3\neq1$ in $GF(7) \Rightarrow \alpha \notin GF(7^{2})$.

So next we try

$\alpha^{7^3}=((\alpha^7)^7)^7=(3\alpha)^7=4\alpha^7=8\alpha=\alpha$ as $8=1$ in $GF(7)$

So $\alpha \in GF(343)$. which means that the splitting field for $\alpha$ is $GF(343)$ over $GF(7).$

What's more $f(x)$ is irreducible over $GF(7)$ as it needs the extension $GF(7)(\alpha)\cong GF(343)$ before it can be split into linear factors.

Comment: This is sound, but of course $x^6-2=(x^3-3)(x^3+3)$ over $GF(7)$ and both those factors are irreducible there.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So I was right about the splitting field being GF(343), but wrong about f(x) being irreducible over GF(7) ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Or am I wrong entirely ?